# 1 Outer Join vs Left join following with Right Join

Tags: oracle11g, left-join, outer-join, query-performance

If Table A has 7k records and Table B has 5 records then Left Outer Join having Table A as Driver gives 7k records and Right Outer Join having Table B as Driver gives 5 records.

However acc to my understanding a FULL OUTER JOIN gives 7k*5 records. Is it always the case or it varies with the Join Clause? If this is always the case, then to merge the data between Table A and Table B, is it not a better option to have LEFT OUTER JOIN results UNION ALL with Right OUTER JOIN results, instead of FULL OUTER JOIN. Forgive my numbness, I'm very tired.:-)

The numbers shown here gives the relative variation of the records we can have between these tables and Table B will actually grow more in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are thinking of as `FULL OUTER JOIN` is actually `CROSS JOIN`, or the Cartesian join operation.  `CROSS JOIN` does return N*M records, where N is the number of records in the left table and M is the number of records in the right table.

`FULL OUTER JOIN` is different -- it's a combination `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN` in a single operation: first the tables are joined and every record resulting from the join operation is returned.

In addition, like a `LEFT JOIN`, rows from the left table that don't have a match on the right will be returned as well and show `NULL` columns for the columns in the right table, and like a `RIGHT JOIN`, rows from the right table that don't have a match on the left will be returned and show `NULL` columns for the columns in the left table.